# Update data-type attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've implemented a typewrite effect via javascript with the HTML code below

```
<a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Hi, Im Si.", "I am Creative.", "I Love Design.", "I Love to Develop." ]'>
```

The typewriting effect uses the `data-type` attribute as the input of the text that will be written. It will write the first sentence `"Hi, Im Si."` then it will be deleted (always with typewriter effect) and the next sentence will be written, and so on. I've already the javascript to do that but it has nothing to do with what I need now.

I would like to have the content of the attribute `data-type` as a jquery variable.

Is there a way to add dynamically the content in the data-type attribute?

To add text in the HTML body via jquery I usually add a `<span class='name_class'></span>` and then with jquery `$(".name_class").html('text_to_insert');`

Is there a way to do something like that but editing the data-type class?

Comment: The `data-type` attribute is not a class. It can be accessed via `element.dataset.type` and must be parsed via `JSON.parse` when retrieving the array. Also, where is your JavaScript code? All you posted was a single HTML element and long-winded text.

Comment: The javascript for typewriting effect doesn't really impact the fact that I want to have the data-type dynamic. I could have posted it but it's just a bunch of javascript that doesn't really have to do with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer was way simpler than I thought; using the `.attr()` in jquery I'm able to change with whatever I want the data-type attribute

So, with the code

```
$(".typewrite").attr('data-type', the_text_you_want_Add_here);
```

I'm able to modify without problems the attribute.

`the_text_you_want_Add_here` bust be a string in the form of `'[ \"the text I want to add here\" ]'`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your desired "typing" should look like, but you can change the output of a target element over a duration of time by updating the content.

```js
const __run = el => {
  const { target, period, type } = el.dataset;
  const targetEl = document.querySelector(target);
  const phrases = JSON.parse(type);
  const duration = Math.ceil(parseInt(period, 10) / phrases.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      targetEl.textContent = `${targetEl.textContent} ${phrases[i]}`.trim();
    }, duration * i);
  }
}

const TypeWrite = (selector = '.typewrite') =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].forEach(__run);

(($) => {
  $.fn.typewrite = function() {
    this.each(function() { __run(this); });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.typewrite').typewrite(); // or you can call :- TypeWrite();
```

```css
.typewrite {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span
  class="typewrite"
  data-target=".output"
  data-period="2000"
  data-type='["Hi,Im Si.","I am Creative.","I Love Design.","I Love to Develop."]'>
</span>
<div class="output"></div>
```

---

If you want to edit the content of the `data-type` attribute, you can do so via plain js or jQuery. Your choice.

### ES6

```js
const getDataType = (el) => JSON.parse(el.dataset.type);
const setDataType = (el, value) => el.dataset.type = JSON.stringify(value);

const typewrite = document.querySelector('.typewrite');

console.log(getDataType(typewrite));

setDataType(typewrite, ['foo', 'bar']);

console.log(getDataType(typewrite));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<span
    class="typewrite"
    data-target=".output"
    data-period="2000"
    data-type='["Hi,Im Si.","I am Creative.","I Love Design.","I Love to Develop."]'>
</span>
```

### jQuery

```js
(($) => {
  $.fn.dataType = function(value) {
    const args = ['type'];
    return this.data.apply(this, value ? [...args, value] : args);
  }
})(jQuery);

const $typewrite = $('.typewrite');

console.log($typewrite.dataType());

$typewrite.dataType(['foo', 'bar']);

console.log($typewrite.dataType());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span
    class="typewrite"
    data-target=".output"
    data-period="2000"
    data-type='["Hi,Im Si.","I am Creative.","I Love Design.","I Love to Develop."]'>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

here we go, you can use the jquery data() method to achieve your goal,
here exactly what you asked for

run snippet and enjoy your code ;)

**EDIT**:

- changed added data to be in array []
- run script once

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var datashow = $(".datadiv");
      $("#dataset").on('click', function() {
        var txt1 = $("#txt1").val();
        var txt2 = $("#txt2").val();
        var txt3 = $("#txt3").val();
        var txt4 = $("#txt4").val();
        $(".datadiv").data("type", [
          txt1,
          txt2,
          txt3,
          txt4
        ]);
      });
      function runeffect() {
      if ($(".datadiv").data("type").length <= 0) {
        console.log("NO thing to show")
      } else {
      var zcntn = $(".datadiv").data("type");
    var zprt = 0;
    var zprtindx = 0;
    var zntrvl;
    var zelm = document.querySelector("#zelm");
    var zcrsr = document.querySelector("#zcrsr");
    function Type() { 
        var text =  zcntn[zprt].substring(0, zprtindx + 1);
        zelm.innerHTML = text;
        zprtindx++;
        if(text === zcntn[zprt]) {
            zcrsr.style.display = 'none';
            clearInterval(zntrvl);
            setTimeout(function() {
                zntrvl = setInterval(Delete, 50);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    function Delete() {
        var text =  zcntn[zprt].substring(0, zprtindx - 1);
        zelm.innerHTML = text;
        zprtindx--;
        if(text === '') {
            clearInterval(zntrvl);
            if(zprt == (zcntn.length - 1))
                //zprt = 0; //use if u need to loop back again
          return;
            else
                zprt++;         
            zprtindx = 0;
            setTimeout(function() {
                zcrsr.style.display = 'inline-block';
                zntrvl = setInterval(Type, 100);
            }, 200);
        }
    }
    zntrvl = setInterval(Type, 100);
      } }
      $("#dataget").on('click', function() {
        
        runeffect();
      });
    });
```

```css
#effectbox {
  text-align: center;
}

#zelm {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: darkblue;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#zcrsr {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  animation: blink .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    background-color: transparent
  }
  20% {
    background-color: darkblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
data-type[1]:
<input type="text" id="txt1" placeholder="first line" value="Hi, Im Si." /><br> data-type[2]:
<input type="text" id="txt2" placeholder="second line" value="I am Creative." /><br> data-type[3]:
<input type="text" id="txt3" placeholder="third line" value="I Love Design." /><br> data-type[4]:
<input type="text" id="txt4" placeholder="fourth line" value="I Love to Develop." />
<input type="button" id="dataset" value="Set data" />
<input type="button" id="dataget" value="Run Effect" />
<br>
<div id="datadiv" class="datadiv" data-type=""> </div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="effectbox">
  <div id="zelm"></div>
  <div id="zcrsr"></div>
</div>
```